# Magento resource: custom selects with OR in where (select orders by status)

Tags: sql, magento, collections, orders

I'm building a custom module and i'm trying get all orders with specific status:

```
$canceledQuery = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->select()
            ->from('mage_sales_flat_order', 'entity_id')
            ->where('status = ?', 'canceled');
```

This works very well. But now i'm trying use OR in where, without success.
I have been try this:

```
$whereCanceled = array();
foreach ($_status as $statusCode => $value) {
    $whereCanceled[] = sprintf('%s=:%s', 'status', $statusCode);
}

$ordersQuery = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->select()
            ->from('mage_sales_flat_order', 'entity_id')
            ->where(implode(' OR ', $whereCanceled));
```

So, I don't know how use OR right in this case. I found no use for this with OR. Any idea?

Comment: whats wrong with your code?

Comment: Does not work. I tried many query with one status with success and then I used implode for get all results just return empty.

Answer (score 1):

instead of **implode** use **join**. magento use join itself.

```
->where(join(' OR ', $orWhere));//$orWhere array of condition
```

you can see in below function magento use **join** for **OR** condition in where clause

```
public function getSystemConfigByPathsAndTemplateId($paths, $templateId)
    {
        $orWhere = array();
        $pathesCounter = 1;
        $bind = array();
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            $pathAlias = 'path_' . $pathesCounter;
            $orWhere[] = 'path = :' . $pathAlias;
            $bind[$pathAlias] = $path;
            $pathesCounter++;
        }
        $bind['template_id'] = $templateId;
        $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
            ->from($this->getTable('core/config_data'), array('scope', 'scope_id', 'path'))
            ->where('value LIKE :template_id')
            ->where(join(' OR ', $orWhere));

        return $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select, $bind);
    }
```

for more reference open file located at [magento]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Email/Template.php

Hope this help you